# SQLite updates won't save or can't execute

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to run a SQL update, and it's returning errors.  For the life of me I can't figure out what's going wrong.  This first attempt errors out with a database can't be opened error, which makes no sense since the second try opens fine:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try{
       db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbnametmp, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
       for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; x++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("color", colors[x]);
            db.update("ColorTable", values, "id=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(ids[x])});
       }
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
       Log.e("nowsciColor", e.getMessage(), e);
    }catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("nowsciColor", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    if (db != null)
       db.close();
```

The second attempt is below.  It does not throw an error, however the actual updates do not occur.  If I query the table right after (both without and with re-opening the DB), the values are the same as they were prior to the update.  I have also tried this without the begin and commits, and as separate sql calls.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try{
       db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbnametmp, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
       String sql = "begin transaction;";
       for (int x = 0; x < ids.length; x++) {
           sql += "update ColorTable set color=" + Integer.toString(colors[x]) + " where id=" + Integer.toString(ids[x]) + ";";
       }
       sql += "commit;";
       db.execSQL(sql);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
       Log.e("nowsciColor", e.getMessage(), e);
    }catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("nowsciColor", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    if (db != null)
       db.close();
```

Running these exact same queries in the DB on a computer works fine.  The database is also not in use by any other application.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a recommendation - you should use the FINALLY keyword right before the IF statement at the end of your code.

Comment: Check the permissions on the SQLite database. It's probably that the program cannot modify the file.

Comment: ASFAIK, you're second method wont work...`exeSQL` takes in just one query.

Comment: There has to be an error, what is it? post your logcat. whats the op of `e.getMessage()`. a tip, you don't need to use `Integer.toString`, using `+` for strings automatically converts those integers.

Comment: Please post your stack trace for your first case. Please use `beginTransaction()`/`setTransactionSuccessful()`/`endTransaction()` for transactions. You may wish to add transactions on your first case to speed up performance. Consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to work with databases.

Answer (score 0):

@Mimisbrunnr: Permissions are good, in fact the App is running with su.

@st0le: I tried as individual and combined statements with the same results, and exceptions weren't firing on the second method, just the first, which was a could not open db.

@CommonsWare: While adding in begin/set/end code, I realized there was one message not printing in the LogCat with my tag so it was slipping past me:

12-27 14:19:21.043: ERROR/Database(1075): Failure 14 (unable to open database file) on 0x2909b0 when executing 'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;'

This database file was copied from one that was in use.  However, the phone was rebooted and it still has this message.  How could the file still be locked?  Is there some temporary file somewhere I need to remove or flag I need to clear?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out.  It was because of the directory I was working in.  Switching to an alternate directory made things work.  I'm guessing that despite the fact that I was running su, the permissions on the directory still created an issue for sqlite.

Comment: You should post comments as comments, extra info to your question by editing it and answers as answers. Not answers in comments to answers which should have been comments. ;)